# Creating a civilization game in java SWING best way to place the map on screen?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a civilization game for a project just wondering what the best way to do it when it reads in a .map file with each line having characters inside of it representing a terrian
so for example t000="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
would be the terrain for the arctic.

I'm just asking what the best method to place this into a view in java SWING, to view the map because what I'm doing right now is creating 2d array of jbuttons and placing the terrain image in those, but I'm thinking it would mess me up when I start adding sprites to the map.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using ImageIcons for each terrain's background, and then perhaps creating a grid of JLabel, each holding the ImageIcon that corresponds to the correct terrain.

**Edit**
If your sprite is to remain on a tile, then add it to the tile as a component (just be sure to give the JLabel a decent layout manager). If the sprite is to move over the tiles, then it should be drawn in a different layer, either on the top level window's glasspane or in a JLayeredPane.

Comment: so when I add sprites on a tile of terrain would the sprite(unit) overlay the tile?